# Unable to make AJAX call on Codepen.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

My codepen written 6 months ago no longer works. The codepen makes an Ajax call to grab data. I am grabbing the data via `jQuery.ajax()`

With a normal http protocol, I am warned that the content from Codepen was loaded via https but the ajax request is via https. When I switch the URL to https, I get a 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error.

How do you execute ajax requests on codepen.io? My example worked as late as June 2017.

[My Codepen](https://codepen.io/stljeff1/pen/dvBvbj)

I found  [this resource](https://blog.codepen.io/2015/07/10/crossorigin-me/) from codepen.io, but crossorigin.me doesn't seem to be online. Are there other resources that would play nicely with Codepen?

Comment: You're contacting "https://www.jeffwilkerson.net" with your ajax call but they don't serve the data over https. It doesnt have much to do with codepen.

Comment: The original data is coming from another site. So, according to what you say, its any web server that doesn't server via https. Is that what you're saying?

Comment: Hey thanks for the insight. I decided to post the data to my github account, and serve it from there.... The fact that the Codepen worked just a few months ago made me wonder what changed with Codepen

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by pushing the data to my github account and served it from there.